# Snowflake 'GET': (VARCHAR(16777216), VARCHAR(12))

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have loaded a JSON file on to a Snowflake stage. 
Now my goal is to COPY the contents of the file into a relational table.

Table is defined as have either varchar or Boolean columns.

```
{
  "requestRefid": "W2W8P",
  "requestid": "kki8786f1b-03eb",
  "requestTypes": [
    "Do not sell it"
  ],
  "subjectTypes": [
    "Current customer"
  ],
  "firstName": "Dan",
  "lastName": "Murrary",
  "email": "k99008a85ki@gmail.com",
  "phone": "410000869",
  "emailValidation": true,
  "phoneValidation": true,
  "message": "Confirm",
}
```

Here is the COPY statement that I am using:

```
copy into TEST."PUBLIC".REQUESTS(REQUESTREFID, REQUESTID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL, PHONE, EMAILVALIDATION, PHONEVALIDATION, IDVALIDATION, MESSAGE, CHANNEL)
   from (select $1:requestRefid, $1:requestid, $1:firstName, $1:lastName, $1:email, $1:phone, $1:emailValidation, $1:phoneValidation, $1:idValidation, $1:message, $1:channel
   from @sf_tut_stage/sample.json t);
```

Here is the error that I get:

> SQL Error [1044] [42P13]:
>
> SQL compilation error: error line 2 at position 18
>
> Invalid argument types for function 'GET': (VARCHAR(16777216),
> VARCHAR(12))
>
> SQL compilation error: error line 2 at position 18
>
> Invalid argument types for function 'GET': (VARCHAR(16777216),
> VARCHAR(12))
>
> SQL compilation error: error line 2 at position 18
>
> Invalid argument types for function 'GET': (VARCHAR(16777216),
> VARCHAR(12))

I am able to query the contents of the JSON file in the stage using following query:

```
select $1
   from @sf_tut_stage/sample.json;
```

What am I doing wrong?

I also tried add following to the copy statement:

```
file_format = (format_name = SF_TUT_CSV_FORMAT));
```

but no luck.

What is the right way to write this statement so it can load items within `$1` to individual relational table columns.

Comment: if you run your select query from the stage while extracting columns from JSON do you get the same error? if so, can you narrow it down to a column that is causing the issue?

Answer (score 7):

Your code is trying to use the `:` syntax to extract a value from the source, but it's still just a varchar, which doesn't allow that syntax. Try this using PARSE_JSON so that SnowFlake knows that it's JSON and can apply that syntax appropriately.

```
copy into TEST."PUBLIC".REQUESTS(REQUESTREFID, REQUESTID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL, PHONE, EMAILVALIDATION, PHONEVALIDATION, IDVALIDATION, MESSAGE, CHANNEL)
from (
    select
        PARSE_JSON($1):requestRefid,
        PARSE_JSON($1):requestid,
        PARSE_JSON($1):firstName,
        PARSE_JSON($1):lastName,
        PARSE_JSON($1):email,
        PARSE_JSON($1):phone,
        PARSE_JSON($1):emailValidation,
        PARSE_JSON($1):phoneValidation,
        PARSE_JSON($1):idValidation,
        PARSE_JSON($1):message,
        PARSE_JSON($1):channel
    from @sf_tut_stage/sample.json t
 );
```

Comment: PARSE_JSON not necessary if you put FILE_FORMAT(TYPE=JSON) just before semicolon.

Comment: In this case, that's likely true, but there are situations like if you have a CSV with multiple columns, one of which is JSON, then you'll need to do this.

Comment: When I try running this select I get following error: 100069 (22P02): Error parsing JSON: incomplete object value, pos 2. When I run following Select, I am able to see the JSON in the result: select t.$1 from @sf_tut_stage_two/ccpasample.json t;

Comment: if parsing the JSON is throwing errors, then it's likely malformed. Or could be an issue with escape characters or some such. but I'm not familiar with that specific error.

Comment: I can reproduce that error (Error parsing JSON: incomplete object value) when my file format for the stage is incorrectly set (default) to CSV, not type = JSON. That might be a clue to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to load JSON data into Relational table.
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/script-data-load-transform-json.html

You need to use parse_json() method.